# Test for martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes

Given a time series, I am trying to determine whether the underlying stochastic process is a martingale or not. Until now, I have deduced that since I know that the process is always bounded after a deterministic time, if I can prove that it is a Brownian motion, I will be done. Is there a standard test for this?

Comment: You started with 'determine whether the underlying stochastic process is a martingale or not' and ended with 'if I can prove that it is a Brownian motion'. What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: @Tarasenya, I am trying to see if the time series is generated by a martingale or not. Wikipedia tells me that a stopped brownian motion is a martingale. So, if I can prove that the time series is generated by a stopped brownian motion, I will be done. I am new to this area, please let me know if I am missing something and the question needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya. Please move this to stat if it will be more suitable there.

Comment: I flagged it, so hopefully a moderator will move it.

Comment: I haven't really done much work with time-series data, so I'm afraid to write a formal answer, but a martingale (based on Wikipedia's statement) is a process where the expected value of the next iteration conditional on all of the previous iterations is equal to the last iteration. Given this, I would like to think that a sufficient test would involve taking the mean of consecutive differences in the time-series and comparing that mean to zero, but I could be way off on this thought.

Comment: @Jonathan: brownian motion can exhibit a trend (such a trend is meaningless, but that is irrelevant), so the mean difference could be non-zero. I can't think of a sensible way to make such a comparison.

Comment: Brownian motion is a martingale, but by no means the only one. But, any continuous martingale is a time-change of Brownian motion -- do we assume the process is continuous?  Please clarify if your testing for general martingale-ness or for Brownian motion.

Comment: I don't work in this area, so I don't know the state of the art, but [Durlauf (1991)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(91)90025-9) and [Hong (1999)](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1999.10473874#) provide suitable tests for whether a series is a martingale.

Comment: Ooops: should have said that any continuous martingale *with finite quadratic variation* is a time change of Brownian motion.